# C program for client using socket on ubuntu linux end not running

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am new to socket programming. I tried to execute a program today. My intention was to check whether the server is available or not. Expecting the output "Failed!" but my program doesn't seem to work. The code shows no error during compilation which makes me wonder if I am using the Linux API correctly. The following is my code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

int main()
    {
    char servIP[]="127.0.0.1";
    char check[]="check";
    int SrvConnect,ret;
    struct sockaddr_in servAdr;
    //printf("Test");
    SrvConnect=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    servAdr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(servIP);
    servAdr.sin_port=htons(1000);
    ret=sendto(SrvConnect,&check,sizeof(check),0,(struct sockaddr *)&servAdr,sizeof(servAdr));
    if(ret==-1)
        printf("\nFailed!\n");
    //printf("Test");
    close(SrvConnect);
    }
```

I have tried placing several output statement at the beginning and end of the code itself (now commented). But even those lines do not execute. Please don't mind if it is a silly mistake. A am really new to this and I have nobody to guide me. Thank You for reading.

Comment: Instead of using `printf` to print the error, use `perror` as it will print a more complete error message based on `errno`.

Comment: Consider reading a good book like http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have created a TCP socket. TCP sockets needs to be *connected* to the server before you can send anything. Try calling [`connect`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/connect) first to connect to the server, and the use [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) or [`send`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/send) to send data.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was silly of me. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @user2051577 Don't worry about it. Everyone looks "silly" when they're new. It'll get better. :)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set `servAdr.sin_family = AF_INET` before connecting.
If connection fail, better use `perror()` to print the error.

Comment: Thank you very much sorry for your trouble!